# Python Sockets multiple file transfers

Tags: python, file-transfer, python-sockets

So I have a python program that basically let's the client connect to the server and send it an excel file which is used as an input for an optimization problem. I then want the server to send the output of this optimization (also an excel file) back to the client. The model itself takes about a minute to solve, and I think this is causing some issues with the client trying to receive the output 'too early'.

The client code:

```
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
HEADER = 64
HEADERSIZE = 10
port = 1234
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
host = "123.45.678.910"

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, port))


filename = "input/Model_Input.xlsx"
filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
s.send(f"{filename}{SEPARATOR}{filesize}".encode())

with open(filename, "rb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        s.sendall(bytes_read)

out_received = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
out_filename, out_filesize = out_received.split(SEPARATOR)
out_filename = os.path.basename(out_filename)
out_filesize = int(out_filesize)

with open(out_filename, "wb") as h:
    while True:
        out_bytes_read = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not out_bytes_read:
            break
        h.write(out_bytes_read)
```

And the server code:

```
SERVER_PORT = 1234
SERVER_HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
SEPARATOR = "<SEPARATOR>"

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))

s.listen(5)
client_socket, address = s.accept()

received = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
filename, filesize = received.split(SEPARATOR)
filename = os.path.basename(filename)
filesize = int(filesize)

with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    while True:
        bytes_read = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not bytes_read:
            break
        f.write(bytes_read)


##################
##  MODEL CODE  ##
##################

outfilename = 'Model_Output.xlsx'
outfilesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
client_socket.send(f"{outfilename}{SEPARATOR}{outfilesize}".encode())

with open(outfilename, "rb") as h:
    while True:
        # read the bytes from the file
        bytes_readed = h.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not bytes_readed:
            break
        client_socket.sendall(bytes_readed)
```

I am able to send the input file to the server and get the model to run, and save the output to storage. However, as soon as I add in the part to try send it back to the client, it gets stuck. It still sends and receives the input file successfully, but then the model never runs. Neither the client nor the server disconnect, they both just seem to be stuck.

Thank you

Comment: Sockets are streams of data with zero guarantee that when you send (say) 4096 bytes that the receiving end will receive those 4096 bytes in one, two, or thirteen or N chunks; you have to include a protocol to ensure the communication works; for example if the <SEPARATOR> Happens to be received as <SEPARAT (with a following recv delivering the OR>) then it will never be recognized at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

I can be very difficult for someone (i.e. me) to remotely debug this type of code, so I can't really point to a particular line of code that is necessarily the problem. If, however, your client and server are running on the same machine, then there is a potential problem in the client code that begins:

```py
with open(out_filename, "wb") as h:
    while True:
        out_bytes_read = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not out_bytes_read:
            break
        h.write(out_bytes_read)
```

When the `open` is executed, this sets the file size to 0. The server, meanwhile is reading this file to transmit it to the file and can possibly find that there are now only 0 bytes. But it has already sent a "header" saying that there are N bytes where N is non-zero. But that is a different problem than the one you describe. But it could be happening in the other direction, also. That is, when the client is sending the file and the server is opening the file for output, it is now zeroing out the file that the client is still reading. The code below solves that problem in both directions. Of course, if your client and server are on different computers not accessing the same files concurrently, then what I have described is not an issue. Not yet, anyway.

I can, however, offer a slightly different approach, which does seem to work:

See the [Using a Socket](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket) section from the **Socket Programming HOWTO** article in the Python 3 Manual. I have adopted the suggestion to use fixed length messages. It's a little more laborious, perhaps, but also a bit more fullproof. That means that if you want to transmit the filename, you have to first transmit the length of the encoded filename as fixed length length message (3 bytes can handle encoded filenames up to 999 bytes in length) and then you can transmit the encode filename. Similarly, we transmit the length of a file as a 9 byte length (left-padded with zeroes), which can handle file sizes up to 999,999,999 bytes (I set the width of 9 arbitrarily). I have two functions, `receive_msg` and `send_msg` that will *robustly* send and receive complete byte messages and can be used by both the client and server. These are modeled on the `MySocket.mysend` and `MySocket.myreceive` methods from the article.

I assumed that the server should be able to handle more than one request before terminating. In fact, it should be able to handle requests concurrently. To that end the server passes a request to a thread pool worker function, `process_request`, for processing. It wasn't clear what the nature of the so-called "Model Code" was. Assuming the function that performs this computation, `process_model`, is CPU-intensive, `process_request`is passed a multiprocessing pool instance that can be used to perform the `process_model` processing so that the CPU-intensive portion of processing will not be limited by the Global Interpreter Lock. If there is no real CPU-intensive processing involved, then remove the code that created the multiprocessing pool and then call `process_model` as a regular function.

**Server Code**

```py
import socket
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
import os.path

BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
SERVER_PORT = 1234
SERVER_HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

def receive_msg(sock, msg_length):
    chunks = []
    bytes_recd = 0
    while bytes_recd < msg_length:
        chunk = sock.recv(min(msg_length - bytes_recd, BUFFER_SIZE))
        if chunk == b'':
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        chunks.append(chunk)
        bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
    return b''.join(chunks)

def send_msg(sock, msg):
    msg_length = len(msg)
    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < msg_length:
        sent = sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalsent = totalsent + sent

def server():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
    s.listen(5)
    process_pool = Pool(5)
    thread_pool = ThreadPool(5)
    while True:
        client_socket, address = s.accept()
        thread_pool.apply_async(process_request, args=(process_pool, client_socket))

def process_request(process_pool, s):
    # Fixed length fields:
    # width 3 for filename length, followed by filename, width 9 for filesize
    filename_size = int(receive_msg(s, 3).decode())
    filename = receive_msg(s, filename_size).decode()
    filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    filesize = int(receive_msg(s, 9).decode())

    msg = receive_msg(s, filesize)
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(msg)

    # Assuming processing the model is CPU-intensive,
    # we use a process pool for doing that:
    out_filename = process_pool.apply(process_model, args=(filename,))
    out_filesize = os.path.getsize(out_filename)
    encoded_filename = out_filename.encode()
    msg1 = b"%03d%s%09dfilesize" % (len(encoded_filename), encoded_filename, out_filesize)
    with open(out_filename, "rb") as h:
        msg2 = h.read()
    send_msg(s, msg1)
    send_msg(s, msg2)

def process_model(filename):
    ...
    # Returned filename should probably be a function of the passed filename
    return 'Model_Output.xlsx' # name of the output file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server()
```

**Client Code**

```py
import socket
import os.path

BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
port = 1234
host = "123.45.678.910"

def receive_msg(sock, msg_length):
    chunks = []
    bytes_recd = 0
    while bytes_recd < msg_length:
        chunk = sock.recv(min(msg_length - bytes_recd, BUFFER_SIZE))
        if chunk == b'':
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        chunks.append(chunk)
        bytes_recd = bytes_recd + len(chunk)
    return b''.join(chunks)

def send_msg(sock, msg):
    msg_length = len(msg)
    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < msg_length:
        sent = sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalsent = totalsent + sent

def client():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    filename = "input/Model_Input.xlsx"
    filesize = os.path.getsize(filename)
    # Fixed length fields:
    # width 3 for filename length, followed by filename, width 9 for filesize
    encoded_filename = filename.encode()
    msg1 = b"%03d%s%09dfilesize" % (len(encoded_filename), encoded_filename, filesize)
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        msg2 = f.read()
    send_msg(s, msg1)
    send_msg(s, msg2)

    out_filename_size = int(receive_msg(s, 3).decode())
    out_filename = receive_msg(s, out_filename_size).decode()
    out_filename = os.path.basename(out_filename)
    out_filesize = int(receive_msg(s, 9).decode())

    msg = receive_msg(s, out_filesize)
    with open(out_filename, "wb") as h:
        h.write(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client()
```

**Update**

The entire programming can greatly be simplified by implementing the service as a Remote Procedure Call. The code is based on [Python Cookbook, 3rd Edition](https://www.dabeaz.com/cookbook.html):

**Server**

```py
import socket
import pickle
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import os.path

SERVER_PORT = 1234
SERVER_HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

class RPCHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self._functions = { }

    def register_function(self, func):
        self._functions[func.__name__] = func

    def handle_connection(self, connection):
        try:
            while True:
                # Receive a message
                func_name, args, kwargs = pickle.loads(connection.recv())
                # Run the RPC and send a response
                try:
                    r = self._functions[func_name](*args,**kwargs)
                    connection.send(pickle.dumps(r))
                except Exception as e:
                    connection.send(pickle.dumps(e))
        except EOFError:
            pass

def server():
    global process_pool

    handler = RPCHandler()
    handler.register_function(process_request)
    sock = Listener((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
    process_pool = Pool(5)
    while True:
        client = sock.accept()
        t = Thread(target=handler.handle_connection, args=(client,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

def process_request(filename, contents):
    filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(contents)

    # Assuming processing the model is CPU-intensive,
    # we use a process pool for doing that:
    out_filename = process_pool.apply(process_model, args=(filename,))
    with open(out_filename, "rb") as h:
        out_contents = h.read()
    return (out_filename, out_contents)

def process_model(filename):
    ...
    # Returned filename should probably be a function of the passed filename
    return 'Model_Output.xlsx' # name of the output file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server()
```

**Client**

```py
import pickle
import socket
import os.path
from multiprocessing.connection import Client

port = 1234
host = "123.45.678.910"

class RPCProxy:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self._connection = connection

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def do_rpc(*args, **kwargs):
            self._connection.send(pickle.dumps((name, args, kwargs)))
            result = pickle.loads(self._connection.recv())
            if isinstance(result, Exception):
                raise result
            return result
        return do_rpc

def client():
    c = Client((host, port))
    proxy = RPCProxy(c)

    filename = "input/Model_Input.xlsx"
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        contents = f.read()
    (out_filename, out_contents) = proxy.process_request(filename, contents)
    out_filename = os.path.basename(out_filename)
    with open(out_filename, "wb") as h:
        h.write(out_contents)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client()
```